# Error when loading keras model with custom objects

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying this [Keras transformers example](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/neural_machine_translation_with_transformer/), and adapted it to save the model once trained and be able to reload it.

I've based my saving of custom objects on this [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/guides/serialization_and_saving/)

Everything works ok when I train the model but when I try to load the model I've got IndexError: list index out of range.

I'm using Python 3.11.8 with Tensorflow 2.16.0 and Keras 3.0.5.

I've created a minimal code that can be copy/pasted and works. I've initialized the datasets with minimal data so no data file is required. Last line is the load_model that generates the error.

The error message is below.:

I've tried the code below. I expect to have the saved model loaded again but instead I've got the following error:

```
loaded_model = load_model('saved_model.keras', 
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\saving\saving_api.py", line 176, in load_model
return saving_lib.load_model(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\saving\saving_lib.py", line 155, in load_model
model = deserialize_keras_object(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\saving\serialization_lib.py", line 711, in deserialize_keras_object
instance = cls.from_config(inner_config)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\model.py", line 492, in from_config
return functional_from_config(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\functional.py", line 555, in functional_from_config
output_tensors = map_tensors(config["output_layers"])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\functional.py", line 552, in map_tensors
return [get_tensor(*v) for v in tensors]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\functional.py", line 552, in 
return [get_tensor(*v) for v in tensors]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\functional.py", line 545, in get_tensor
layer_output_tensors = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index].output_tensors
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\trackable\data_structures.py", line 432, in **getitem**
return self._storage[key]
~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

------------------------------------ FULL CODE ----------------------------------------------

```
'''################################################
###      COMPATIBILITY : KERAS      3.0.5    ###
###                      TENSORFLOW 2.16.0   ###
###                      PYTHON     3.11.8   ###
################################################'''

'''-------------------- RUN PARAMETERS -----------------'''
vocab_size = 5000
sequence_length = 20
batch_size = 64
epochs = 1  # This should be at least 30 for convergence

import os

os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "tensorflow"

#import random
import string
import re
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import data as tf_data
from tensorflow import strings as tf_strings

import keras
from keras.models import load_model
from keras import layers
from keras import ops   #attention -> this works in keras 3.0.5 and not in keras 2.15.0
from keras.layers import TextVectorization

def custom_standardization(input_string):
    lowercase = tf_strings.lower(input_string)
    return tf_strings.regex_replace(lowercase, "[%s]" % re.escape(strip_chars), "")

train_pairs = [['Hello','Hola'],['Bye','Adios']]
val_pairs = [['Hello','Hola'],['Bye','Adios']]
test_pairs = [['Hello','Hola'],['Bye','Adios']]

print("----------------------------------------- Vectorizing the text data ----------------------------")
strip_chars = string.punctuation + "¿"
strip_chars = strip_chars.replace("[", "")
strip_chars = strip_chars.replace("]", "")

eng_vectorization = TextVectorization(
max_tokens=vocab_size,
output_mode="int",
output_sequence_length=sequence_length,
)
spa_vectorization = TextVectorization(
max_tokens=vocab_size,
output_mode="int",
output_sequence_length=sequence_length + 1,
standardize=custom_standardization,
)
train_eng_texts = [pair[0] for pair in train_pairs]
train_spa_texts = [pair[1] for pair in train_pairs]
eng_vectorization.adapt(train_eng_texts)
spa_vectorization.adapt(train_spa_texts)

def format_dataset(eng, spa):
    eng = eng_vectorization(eng)
    spa = spa_vectorization(spa)
    return (
        {
            "encoder_inputs": eng,
            "decoder_inputs": spa[:, :-1],
        },
        spa[:, 1:],
    )

def make_dataset(pairs):
    eng_texts, spa_texts = zip(*pairs)
    eng_texts = list(eng_texts)
    spa_texts = list(spa_texts)
    dataset = tf_data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((eng_texts, spa_texts))
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.map(format_dataset)
    return dataset.cache().shuffle(2048).prefetch(16)

train_ds = make_dataset(train_pairs)
val_ds = make_dataset(val_pairs)

print("----------------------------------------- Building the model ----------------------------")
# Clear all previously registered custom objects
keras.saving.get_custom_objects().clear()

@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable(name="TransformerEncoder")
class TransformerEncoder(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, dense_dim, num_heads, **kwargs):
        #super().__init__(**kwargs)
        super(TransformerEncoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.embed_dim = embed_dim
        self.dense_dim = dense_dim
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.attention = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
            num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim, name='te1'
        )
        self.dense_proj = keras.Sequential(
            [
                layers.Dense(dense_dim, activation="relu", name='te2'),
                layers.Dense(embed_dim, name='te3'),
            ]
        )
        self.layernorm_1 = layers.LayerNormalization(name='te4')
        self.layernorm_2 = layers.LayerNormalization(name='te5')
        self.supports_masking = True

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super().build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs, mask=None):
        if mask is not None:
            padding_mask = ops.cast(mask[:, None, :], dtype="int32")
        else:
            padding_mask = None

        attention_output = self.attention(
            query=inputs, value=inputs, key=inputs, attention_mask=padding_mask
        )
        proj_input = self.layernorm_1(inputs + attention_output)
        proj_output = self.dense_proj(proj_input)
        return self.layernorm_2(proj_input + proj_output)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update(
            {
                "embed_dim": self.embed_dim,
                "dense_dim": self.dense_dim,
                "num_heads": self.num_heads
            }
        )
        return config

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        return cls(**config)    

@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable(name="PositionalEmbedding")
class PositionalEmbedding(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, sequence_length, vocab_size, embed_dim, **kwargs):
        #super().__init__(**kwargs)
        super(PositionalEmbedding, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.token_embeddings = layers.Embedding(
            input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embed_dim, name='pe1'
        )
        self.position_embeddings = layers.Embedding(
            input_dim=sequence_length, output_dim=embed_dim, name='pe2'
        )
        self.sequence_length = sequence_length
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size
        self.embed_dim = embed_dim

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super().build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        length = ops.shape(inputs)[-1]
        positions = ops.arange(0, length, 1)
        embedded_tokens = self.token_embeddings(inputs)
        embedded_positions = self.position_embeddings(positions)
        return embedded_tokens + embedded_positions

    def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
        if mask is None:
            return None
        else:
            return ops.not_equal(inputs, 0)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update(
            {
                "sequence_length": self.sequence_length,
                "vocab_size": self.vocab_size,
                "embed_dim": self.embed_dim
            }
        )
        return config

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        return cls(**config)


@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable(name="TransformerDecoder")
class TransformerDecoder(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, latent_dim, num_heads, **kwargs):
        #super().__init__(**kwargs)
        super(TransformerDecoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.embed_dim = embed_dim
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.attention_1 = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
            num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim, name='td1'
        )
        self.attention_2 = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
            num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim, name='td2'
        )
        self.dense_proj = keras.Sequential(
            [
                layers.Dense(latent_dim, activation="relu", name='td3'),
                layers.Dense(embed_dim, name='td4'),
            ]
        )
        self.layernorm_1 = layers.LayerNormalization(name='td5')
        self.layernorm_2 = layers.LayerNormalization(name='td6')
        self.layernorm_3 = layers.LayerNormalization(name='td7')
        self.supports_masking = True

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super().build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs, encoder_outputs, mask=None):
        causal_mask = self.get_causal_attention_mask(inputs)
        if mask is not None:
            padding_mask = ops.cast(mask[:, None, :], dtype="int32")
            padding_mask = ops.minimum(padding_mask, causal_mask)
        else:
            padding_mask = None

        attention_output_1 = self.attention_1(
            query=inputs, value=inputs, key=inputs, attention_mask=causal_mask
        )
        out_1 = self.layernorm_1(inputs + attention_output_1)

        attention_output_2 = self.attention_2(
            query=out_1,
            value=encoder_outputs,
            key=encoder_outputs,
            attention_mask=padding_mask,
        )
        out_2 = self.layernorm_2(out_1 + attention_output_2)

        proj_output = self.dense_proj(out_2)
        return self.layernorm_3(out_2 + proj_output)

    def get_causal_attention_mask(self, inputs):
        input_shape = ops.shape(inputs)
        batch_size, sequence_length = input_shape[0], input_shape[1]
        i = ops.arange(sequence_length)[:, None]
        j = ops.arange(sequence_length)
        mask = ops.cast(i >= j, dtype="int32")
        mask = ops.reshape(mask, (1, input_shape[1], input_shape[1]))
        mult = ops.concatenate(
            [ops.expand_dims(batch_size, -1), ops.convert_to_tensor([1, 1])],
            axis=0,
        )
        return ops.tile(mask, mult)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update(
            {
                "embed_dim": self.embed_dim,
                "latent_dim": self.latent_dim,
                "num_heads": self.num_heads
            }
        )
        return config

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        return cls(**config)

print("-----------------------------------------Next, we assemble the end-to-end model.------------------------")
embed_dim = 256
latent_dim = 2048
num_heads = 8

encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None,), dtype="int64", name="encoder_inputs")
x = PositionalEmbedding(sequence_length, vocab_size, embed_dim)(encoder_inputs)
encoder_outputs = TransformerEncoder(embed_dim, latent_dim, num_heads)(x)
encoder = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_outputs)

decoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None,), dtype="int64", name="decoder_inputs")
encoded_seq_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None, embed_dim), name="decoder_state_inputs")
x = PositionalEmbedding(sequence_length, vocab_size, embed_dim)(decoder_inputs)
x = TransformerDecoder(embed_dim, latent_dim, num_heads)(x, encoded_seq_inputs)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5, name='sa1')(x)
decoder_outputs = layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation="softmax", name='sa2')(x)
decoder = keras.Model([decoder_inputs, encoded_seq_inputs], decoder_outputs)

decoder_outputs = decoder([decoder_inputs, encoder_outputs])
transformer = keras.Model(
    [encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], 
    decoder_outputs, 
    name="transformer"
)

#transformer.summary()
transformer.compile(
    optimizer="rmsprop", 
    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", 
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)

print("-----------------------------------------Training our model------------------------")

history = transformer.fit(train_ds, epochs=epochs, validation_data=val_ds)

print("--------------------------------- saving model -----------------------")

transformer.save("saved_model.keras")

print("--------------------------------- loading saved model -----------------------")

loaded_model = load_model('saved_model.keras', 
            custom_objects = {
                "TransformerEncoder": TransformerEncoder, 
                "PositionalEmbedding": PositionalEmbedding, 
                "TransformerDecoder": TransformerDecoder}
                , compile=False
                )
```